# F# and FSharp.Configuration Check if there is a configuration file

Tags: f#, app-config

I have a question, I am using FSharp.Configuration (https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/YamlConfigProvider.html) library to read configuration file in my project using Yaml provider. Well it all works well and good but I started to wonder how to detect if there is no configuration file, if some no good user deleted this file.

I could replace it with some default hard coded config. But documentarian says none about it.

Anyone maybe solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values from the config file passed to the TP at compile time are stored as default values (right in the generated code), except lists of compound types, which will always be empty due to the TP restriction. So, when you instantiate a TP at runtime, it's "filled" with the default values already. If you need to fill it with different values, you can load a file, a string, or set individual properties in code. Maybe it would be a good idea to add an ability to load config from resources, but I'm not sure it's an idiomatic way in .NET world (in contrast with, say, Scala).